# Fault in Multiple Realloc C Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc, realloc

my program fails always in the 4th realloc and I don't understand why it makes the 3 first good and then it fails. I'm using triple pointer and I've tried to debugate and all works good until the 4th realloc when it says that its out of scope and segmention fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rellenar(int ***movimiento, int mov, int discos) {

    int j, pos, mov2, ***movimiento2;
    mov2 = mov + 1;

    movimiento = realloc(movimiento, mov2 * sizeof (int **));
    movimiento[mov] = malloc(3 * sizeof (int *)); //3 de torres

    for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        movimiento[mov][j] = malloc(discos);
    }
    printf("%d\n", mov);
    for (pos = 0; pos < discos; pos++) {
        movimiento[mov][0][pos] = 1;
        movimiento[mov][1][pos] = 1;
        movimiento[mov][2][pos] = 1;
        printf("%d", movimiento[mov-1][0][pos]);
        printf("%d", movimiento[mov-1][1][pos]);
        printf("%d\n", movimiento[mov-1][2][pos]);        
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int ***movimiento, i, j, movs = 1, discos = 4, pos, mov;
    movimiento = malloc(movs * sizeof (int **));
    for (i = 0; i < movs; ++i) {
        movimiento[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof (int *)); //3 de torres

        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) //3 de torres
        {
            movimiento[i][j] = malloc(discos);

        }
    }

    for (pos = 0; pos < discos; pos++) {
        movimiento[0][0][pos] = discos - pos;
        movimiento[0][1][pos] = 0;
        movimiento[0][2][pos] = 2;
    }
    for (pos = 0; pos < discos; pos++) {
        printf("%d", movimiento[0][0][pos]);
        printf("%d", movimiento[0][1][pos]);
        printf("%d\n", movimiento[0][2][pos]);
    }


    for (mov = 1; mov < 6; mov++) {
        rellenar(movimiento, mov, discos);
    }
 }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `movimiento[i][j] = malloc(discos);` --> `movimiento[i][j] = malloc(discos * sizeof(int));`. Same for other places where you do the similar `malloc`.

Comment: Even better advice: If you are on a supported platform (e.g. Linux) run [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you find memory corruptions like this. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: As kaylum said, you forgot to multiply `discos` by `sizeof(int)` to allocate the proper amount of memory for `movemiento[i][j]`.  As a result, you are writing past the memory you allocated, corrupting your memory state.  All bets are off once that happens.

Comment: Also `movimiento = realloc(movimiento,...` can't update caller side variable.

Comment: But sizeof(int) is always 1 so it doesn't change anything. I've tried but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you mean with can't update calle side variable? Can you explain it please?

Comment: Passing of the argument in C is call by value. So, Change of argument of the function is a change to a local variable.

Comment: So how I return this value correctly to the main? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: use `****` or return value.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I've changed ***movimiento for ****movimiento in the rellenar function. But it doesn't work. Where else I have to change ***movimiento?

Comment: E.g `***movimiento2 = *movimiento;`.. `movimiento2 = realloc(movimiento2,` .... `*movimiento = movimiento2;`

Answer (score -1):

Rather than triple-nested mallocs and reallocs, which are inefficient and hard to keep straight, just do your allocation in a single shot:

```
size_t total = mov2 * 3 * discos;
int* movimiento = malloc(total * sizeof(int));
```

Now you can fill it like this:

```
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < total; ++ii)
    movimiento[ii] = 1;
```

Then make an indexing function:

```
int* get_cell(int* matrix, size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, size_t max_y, size_t max_z) {
    return &matrix[x*max_y*max_z + y*max_z + z];
}
```

So then:

```
int two = *get_cell(movimiento, mov, 1, pos, 3, discos);
```

And when it's time to release the memory, it's simply:

```
free(movimiento);
```

Comment: The problem is that I was asked to do it with realloc. So any idea of what is not working in my code?